# how to position view base on min(X or Y) not mid(X or y) SwiftUI

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

I want to position blue view based on topTrailing anchor like this

[image: image 2]

not like

[image: Img]

this is my code Xcode12 beta 3

```
struct Test: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment:.topLeading){
            Color.black
            Rectangle()
                .frame(width:100, height: 100, alignment: .topLeading)
                .position(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
        }
        .frame(width: 250, height: 250, alignment: .topLeading)
    }
}
```

how do I do that

Comment: too many *not*, so, do you want image 1 or image 2? or skatch somehow what do you expect.

Comment: sorry about those "nots"
I edited the question

Answer (score 0):

To position relative to the top leading origin:

Use

```
.offset(x: 0, y: 0)
```

in place of

```
.position(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
```

Comment: I assumed you might want to use offsets other than (0, 0). If you use (10, 10) for instance you will see the top left origin offset by 10 points in each direction.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `position`, it disables automatic layout, because specifies explicit defined location in parent coordinates relative to own anchor point.

[image: demo]

```
struct Test: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment:.topLeading){
            Color.black
            Rectangle()
                .frame(width:100, height: 100, alignment: .topLeading)
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
        }
        .frame(width: 250, height: 250, alignment: .topLeading)
    }
}
```